# How update or delete PDF file (link) of downloadable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, downloadable, download-link

In Magento 2, how can I update the PDF file of a download product so that old links refers to the new PDF?

I think there are 2 ways to try that:

1. I can load every links (in this case THE link) of the product and delete them
   and set the new one. I think it will not be a problem for purchased links in the past because the link interfaces refer to the product sku by this save function:

   ```
   $link_repository->save($sku, $link_interface);
   ```

   The product will not be deleted and will conserve its old sku, so the links will be actualized with a new one (right...?).
2. I can try to change the base64 encoded content of the Link used to set the Link to the product:

   ```
   $content_interface->setFileData($b64pdf);
   ```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link_repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Downloadable\Api\LinkRepositoryInterface');
$link_interface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface');   

#DELETE OLD
$old_links = $link_repository->getList($product->getSku());
foreach ($old_links as $old_link) {
    $link_repository->delete($old_link->getId());                               
}
```